# How to open a comboBox on single click on textblock in windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I am currently migrating my Windows Phone App to  Windows 8.1 App and there is requirement that when user tap on TextBlock, ComboBox should open. Initially comboBox is collapsed. I tried but what actually happens is, first the comboBox becomes visible on first tap and on second tap the comboBox opens. I did this in Windows Phone 8 using ListPicker, in ListPicker there was a method ListPicker.Open() using which it opened at single tap, but something similar is not available. Please can anyone suggest what can be done. I have created TextBlock and ComboBox dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.isdropdownopen.aspx) property to `true`.

(I've just googled it, can not test it right now. Let me if it works)

Comment: I tried this before not working, on first tap, ComboBox becomes visible then the drop down opens . Do you know how to create Flyout for textblock dynamically? I was thinking of it as second option.

Comment: Basically it opens when you set this property to `true` twice?

Comment: No, i have added only once ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen property to true.

Comment: You said that on first tap combo box becomes visible. On second tap on textblock, it dropsdown itself.

Comment: but I want to do, both this procedure on single tap, if don't add ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen property then also, the behaviour is same.